# Delete all xml tags between strings in string with python and regexp

Tags: python, regex

I have string:

```
...<w:t> Name</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria" w:hAnsi="Cambria"/><w:b/><w:sz w:val="28"/><w:szCs w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>:</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/></w:rPr><w:t>{{</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:i/><w:iCs/></w:rPr><w:t>test</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:i/><w:iCs/></w:rPr><w:t>.name</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/></w:rPr><w:t>}} <w:t>....
```

And i need script which will delete all tags(<...>) between {{ and }}
But do not delete between pairs of characters, e.g:

```
The result of:
{{ <wr> test.name1 <wr> }} <wr><wr> {{ <wr> test.name2 <wr> }} 
will be:
{{ test.name1 }} <wr><wr> {{ test.name2 }} 
not:
{{ test.name1 }} {{ test.name2 }}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are numerous websites that allow you to test your regex pretty quickly. E.g. http://www.regexr.com/ or http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need single regular expression, you may combine substitutions:

```
    import re
    s='{{ <wr> test.name1 <wr> }} <wr><wr> {{ <wr> test.name2 <wr> }}'
    re.sub(r'({{[^{}]+}})', lambda x: re.sub(r'<[a-zA-Z0-9:-]+>', '', x.group(0)), s)
    '{{  test.name1  }} <wr><wr> {{  test.name2  }}'
```

Comment: thx! But that solution do not work for string from question :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
import re

TAG_RE = re.compile(r'\{\{(\s*<[^>]+>|\s*)(\s*.*?\s*)(<[^>]+>\s*|\s*)\}\}')

def remove_tags2(text):
    return TAG_RE.sub('{{ \g<2> }}', text)

remove_tags2("sdfgsd {{ <wr> blablalba sdf asf asga sfas asd </wr> }} <wr><wr> {{<wr>alsdfhaksdhfkajg<wr>}}")
```

Output:

```
'sdfgsd {{  blablalba sdf asf asga sfas asd  }} <wr><wr> {{ alsdfhaksdhfkajg }}'
```

Comment: thx! But that solution do not work for string from question :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on Eugene answer:

```
import re

s='...<w:t> Name</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria" w:hAnsi="Cambria"/><w:b/><w:sz w:val="28"/><w:szCs w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>:</w:t></w:r><w:r><$

print re.sub(r'({{[^{}]+}})', lambda x: re.sub(r'<[^>]+>', '', x.group(0)), s)
```

output:

```
...<w:t> Name</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria" w:hAnsi="Cambria"/><w:b/><w:sz w:val="28"/><w:szCs w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>:</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/></w:rPr><w:t>{{ test.name }} <w:t>....
```